# Vue.js not responding to mouse events after changing keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I just found strange behavior in Vue. After changing keys for components, my custom mouse event bindings don't work anymore. I know we should not mix jQuery with Vue but this is just a test. I don't understand why this is happening. What is the explanation for this? Does it have something to do with the Virtual DOM? I am looking more for an explanation of why this is happening than for a solution.

I noticed that when I inspect the DOM, everything looks correct. But the mouse events do not work.

**Here is how it works.**

```
1. When you click on the two green buttons it should print out the data-key attribute for that button.
2. Then click on the "Change keys" button and the keys for components will change
3. Now click again on the green buttons but they will no longer print their data-key attributes to the screen.
```

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="key1+=5; key2++">Change keys</button>

  <my-button :data-key="key1" :key="key1"></my-button>
  <my-button :data-key="key2" :key="key2"></my-button>

  <div id="console"></div>
</div>

Vue.component('my-button', {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },

  template: `<button
                class="btn"
                style="background: lightgreen"
                @click="count++">
                You clicked me {{ count }} times.
             </button>`
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
  },

  mounted()
  {
    $('.btn').mousedown(function(event) {
      $('#console').append(
        'data-key: ' +
        event.target.getAttribute('data-key') +
        '<br>'
      )
    })
  }          
})
```

Here is a working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/queeeeenz/zuye12oL/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're changing keys, you're re-rendering the elements. And your events are bound on the initial buttons. The new ones have no events attached.

If you want to bind for all present and future buttons in your app, you have to bind to an element that doesn't go away, with a slightly different syntax:

```
$('#app').on('mousedown', '.btn', function(event) {
  $('#console').append(
    'data-key: ' +
    event.target.getAttribute('data-key') +
    '<br>'
  )
})
```

See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/j1h2y0wd/).

Why it works: With direct binding syntax (your case), the selector is evaluated at the time of binding. With second (delegated event), it's evaluated at the time of the event, against the target of the event.

Read a full explanation on jquery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) page, under "Delegated events" section.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how this new syntax works differently than the one I used before?

Comment: The gist of it is that you need to find to an element which is in DOM at the time of binding ***and*** the time of the event. For performance reasons, you want to find the smallest possible parent to do it (don't go for `<body>` or you'll soon drawn it in events).

Comment: The new syntax is not so new. Most of of the event related jQuery methods are shorthands for `.on()` and each of them lists the full syntax at the very top of the documentation page. Second and third params can be omitted, while the last one is the handler. Also note first param, though called `events`, is always a string: so you'll use `mousedown mouseup` to bind to both, not an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes more sense now.